# Starting a java program from shellscript

Tags: java, linux, shell, unix

I'm complete Linux newbie, but still want to provide a simple way for Linux users to start my Java program.
Therefore I want to create a shellscript.

I can't test my script so I'll have to ask here if this is working correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp "bin";"extres/junit.jar" data.ProgramOne
exit 0
```

Comment: This looks good. You don't need the quotes and the "exit 0" line could be removed. If this is something professional and complex, you should test it on linux (use a virtual machine or a ubuntu distribution that you can test without installation) because the launching of the application isn't generally the biggest porting problem.

Comment: Question: Why can't you test your script? Why not download some virtualizer like VirtualBox, install Ubuntu and start testing? It's not like in the old days where you needed a separate machine for such testing scenarios...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in path delimiter. It is `;` on Windows and `:` on Linux.
Moreover you should not wrap each classpath fragment with `""`. On unix you can escape spaces and other forbidden characters using `\`. So, I'd re-write the java execution line as:

`java -cp bin:extres/junit.jar data.ProgramOne`

This will run when you are executing script from your app directory where you have subdirectory `bin` and `extres`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

java -cp "bin:extres/junit.jar" data.ProgramOne

Answer (score 1):

Java under Unixes uses `:` as the separator in the classpath, so you'd need (the quotes are not necessary):

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp bin:extres/junit.jar data.ProgramOne
```